# What is it about this question that makes it borderline "low quality"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

After asking this question (my first post here, by the way):

[Is content inside IE conditional comments indexed by search engines?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/23872/is-content-inside-ie-conditional-comments-indexed-by-search-engines)

...I was met with a comment from a moderator that indicated my question may not be up to snuff with the standards of this site, based solely on the content I used as an example (see question for reference):

> Is that content an actual example? – John Conde♦
>
> @JohnConde: No it's
> not a real example. It could be, but theoretically it could be
> anything. Why did you ask me if the example content was real or not, does
> that have any bearing? – Madmartigan
>
> I asked because if it was it would definitely answer your question
> making it a low quality question. But it didn't so your question was a
> high quality question. We like high quality questions. :) – John
> Conde♦

I left a couple more comments and never got a reply, so I'm wondering a few things. In the context of the question I asked:

- Why would my example content being a real example make the question easily "answerable"? If this is true, what would that answer have been?
- Why does the question merely being "answerable" mean that it is low quality?

I'm not new to Stack Exchange, but I am new *here*, so I may just have a fundamental misunderstanding of what this place is all about, or perhaps there was something about my question that was borderline. I believe it was also re-tagged inappropriately by the moderator, which led to further confusion on my end.

Can someone clarify any of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why would my example content being a real example make the question easily "answerable"? If this is true, what would that answer have been?

"Look at this painting of a pipe. Is it a painting of a pipe?"
If your screenshot were a real example, and the snippet were in a conditional comment, then the answer to the question would be "Yes, they're indexed, based on your own example."

Of course, sometimes this situation is a result of the person mistakenly asking the wrong question altogether.

Comment: OK I see what happened then, the commenter simply didn't: A) Read the question text fully. B) Read the text in the example image fully... Is this right? I said "I don't want to see something like this" followed by an image of search results that said "My Website" with the URL "example.com". I don't see how anyone could have thought that was a real screen shot, but apparently that's what happened? "Real example" was misinterpreted as "this actually happened", instead of "this is a real example of text on my website that's in a conditional comment, I wonder if it could get indexed".

Comment: I guess that's pretty funny then.